# How do I update a table with a select statement that produces multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have two tables:

```
[Table container]
id int
<some more fields>
latest_measurement int

[Table measurement]
id int
container_id int
unixtime bigint
```

Now I want to update the sensors table `latest_measurement` column based on the latest measurement from the measurement table. I have prepared the subquery to return the latest measurement per `sensor_id` and this works:

```
SELECT m.fill_level
from measurement m
inner join (
    select m.container_id, MAX(m.unixtime) as maxdate from measurement m GROUP BY container_id
) m2
on m2.container_id = m.container_id
where m.unixtime = m2.maxdate
```

But if I then use this query in my update statement as follows, it fails with an exception:

```
UPDATE container
SET latest_fill_level = (
    SELECT m.fill_level
    from measurement m
    inner join (
        select m.container_id, MAX(m.unixtime) as maxdate from measurement m GROUP BY container_id
) m2
    on m2.container_id = m.container_id
    where m.unixtime = m2.maxdate
    and container.id = m.container_id)
```

And finally, here's the exception:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

How do I write an update statement that can update multiple rows with their respective values from a SELECT statement that produces multiple values?

Comment: Can you provide how many records does your inner query result? (`select m.fill_level from ...`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery doesn't break ties.  If there are multiple measurements with the latest `unixtime`, it will return multiple rows.  Because SQL Server can't know which row it is supposed to use to update the column, it will raise a `Subquery returned more than 1 value.` error.

You could use `row_number()` to break ties:

```
update  c
set     latest_measurement = m.fill_level
from    container c
join    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by container_id
                    order by unixtime desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    measurement
        ) m
on      c.id = m.container_id
        and m.rn = 1 -- Latest measurement only
```

Or alternatively, you can break ties with a `top 1` clause:

```
update  container
set     latest_measurement = 
        (
        select  top 1 fill_level
        from    measurement m
        where   container.id = m.container_id
        order by
                unixtime desc
        )
```

Comment: Ok, I think I got the point. But what I need to do is to update ALL rows in the container table to re-new the latest measurement value. Can I do this with a sql query or is there no way around a procedure?

Comment: Both queries will update all rows in the `container` table.  Try them

Comment: Andomar, tell me what the name of the second pattern: update with correlated subquery?

Comment: Finally I understood the second query... I was thinking much too complicated :-) Thanks for your support!

Comment: How do I do this in SQL Server?